# Need to refactor to the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax

Tags: ruby, chef-recipe, rubocop

I have a recipe that has the following code that is failing a lint test:

```
service 'apache' do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
end
```

It fails with the error:

```
Use the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax.
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
```

Not sure what the new syntax looks like... can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A new syntax for hash literals whose keys are symbols was introduced in Ruby 1.9. Hashes commonly use the "hash rocket" operator to separate the key and the value:

```
a_hash = { :a_key => 'a_value' }
```

In Ruby 1.9 this syntax is valid but whenever the key is a symbol it's also possible to write it as:

```
a_hash = { a_key: 'a_value' }
```

And as the Ruby style guide says, you should prefer to use the Ruby 1.9 hash literal syntax when your hash keys are symbols [(see)](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#hash-literals):

```
# non-recommended
hash = { :one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3 }

# recommended
hash = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
```

And as an additional hint; don't mix the Ruby 1.9 hash syntax with hash rockets in the same hash literal. When you've got keys that are not symbols stick to the hash rockets syntax [(see)](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-mixed-hash-syntaces):

```
# non-recommended
{ a: 1, 'b' => 2 }

# recommended
{ :a => 1, 'b' => 2 }
```

So you could try with;

```
service 'apache' do
  supports status: true, restart: true, reload: true
end
```

If you want to see what's the Rubocop "way" you can run this in the command line, this will autocorrect your code only for the `HashSyntax` warnings or flags:

```
rubocop --only HashSyntax --auto-correct
```

Comment: How would I type a hash with 2 symbols, like: {:key => :value, :key2 => :value2} ?

Comment: Just `{ key: :value, key2: :value2 }`, both values, hash key and hash value are symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
service 'apache' do
  supports status: true, restart: true, reload: true
end
```

You can use this new syntax when you have symbols as keys.