# Routes alias in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my project I have a class called City and I have created the aliases BirthCity and ResidenceCity. I want to change the routes.rb file in the correct way.

I've tried adding

```
resources :birth_cities,  :path => :cities, as: => :cities 
resources :residence_cities,  :path => :cities, as: => :cities
```

Every time I call birth_city_path, I want it to be referenced to city_path. But I'm getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected => (SyntaxError)
...ties,  :path => :cities, as: => :cities 
...                             ^~
```

Any ideas? I've also tried modified it like this:

```
resources :birth_cities,:path => :cities,:as 'cities'
```

but it doesn't work anyway.

EDIT: now the sintax is corret but I'm getting another error

```
undefined method `birth_cities_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f4b3cfcd6c0>:0x00007f4b21303950>
```

for the following line

```
<%= guiFieldAutocomplete(f, :birth_city_id, { data: { autocomplete_source: birth_cities_path(col: "json_recordset_name") }}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
as: => :cities
```

should be

```
:as => :cities
```

syntax for hash literals

```
{ :a => 3, "b" => 4 }
```

new syntax for hash literals with symbol keys

```
{ a: 3, b: 4 }
```

this is equals to

```
{ :a => 3, :b => 4 }
```

just shorter

you're kinda mixing these two syntaxes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are confused between new and old hash syntax.

You should replace this code:

```
resources :birth_cities,  :path => :cities, as: => :cities
resources :residence_cities,  :path => :cities, as: => :cities
```

with

```
resources :birth_cities,  :path => :cities, :as => :cities
resources :residence_cities,  :path => :cities, :as => :cities
```

Changing `as: => :cities` to `:as => :cities`

Read more about this syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005425/4797110